# Parsing a product into monomials in python fast?

Tags: python, parsing, eval, sympy

I have a monomial of the form  `m` and I want to parse it into an expression having exponents.

```
m = "n0*n0"     
Sympy(n0)
parse_expr(n0*n0)
```

This gives me the following correct output:

```
n0**2
```

The problem is I have millions of such monomials with thousands of parameters in a dataframe column and right now I do an apply on them to parse them, this takes forever. Is there a better solution ? `eval` requires me to give a value to `n0` I dont want to evaluate I just want to arse monomial like this into a succinct representation.

Comment: It would be better if you could demonstrate your problem with an example that is slow. Perhaps show what a few different monomials look like and make a loop over them that is slow or something.

Comment: `a dataframe column` - are you using `pandas`?  `pandas.apply` is generally quite slow, since it is a `python` level iteration.  The column is object dtype containing Python strings.  And `sympy` is a complex package built on Python, and generally quite slow.  So I can see why applying `parse_expr` to Pandas columns will take a lot time.   "fast" requires compiled code (as done with `numpy` methods) - that isn't available here.

Comment: Does your data have a lot of repeats of information? If so, I would recommend the functools.lru_cache decorator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an `isympy` session:

```
In [38]: parse_expr("n0*n0")
Out[38]: 
  2
n₀ 

In [39]: type(_)
Out[39]: sympy.core.power.Pow
```

The parsing takes a string, an returns a `sympy` expression.

That is not a particularly fast operation:

```
In [40]: timeit parse_expr("n0*n0")
524 µs ± 79.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Compare that with doing a simple string replace:

```
In [42]: "n0*n0".replace("*n0","**2")
Out[42]: 'n0**2'

In [43]: timeit "n0*n0".replace("*n0","**2")
118 ns ± 1.04 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

This is the first time I've seen someone trying to use `sympy` with `pandas`.  People do try to use it with `numpy`, often with confusing results.  Usually `sympy.lambdify` is only reliable way of creating a `numpy` function from a `sympy` expression.  `sympy` is good for doing  algebraic math, but I can't picture it being useful with large dataframes.